# Thingsboard Performance Test - Gatling

Tags: mqtt, performance-testing, gatling, thingsboard, broker

I'm trying to do performance test using the https://github.com/thingsboard/gatling-mqtt project.

Although current versions of the tools are a bit different, I managed to have it running.
I've tested a couple of basic scripts with Gatling using HTTP and Gatling worked as expected.

But when using the scripts provided with the tool, that use the plugin for MQTT it does not work.
In fact it runs but it doesn't do anything. No connections, no logs, no reports, no errors.

On the other tests it increments the global OK=0 as the test progresses, and generates logs and reports.
But as you can see below, when running with the MQTT plugin it doesn't increment the count
.

```
Simulation MqttSimulation_localhost started...

================================================================================
2021-10-14 17:55:02                                           5s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


---- MQTT Test -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 10     / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2021-10-14 17:55:07                                          10s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


---- MQTT Test -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 10     / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2021-10-14 17:55:12                                          15s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )


---- MQTT Test -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--------------------------------------------------------------------------]  0%
          waiting: 0      / active: 10     / done:0
================================================================================


================================================================================
2021-10-14 17:55:17                                          20s elapsed
---- Requests ------------------------------------------------------------------
> Global                                                   (OK=0      KO=0     )

... and it goes on forever
```

Any ideas on what could be happening?
I would certainly appreciate any help on this!

Thank you!

Comment: This plugin is an old fork of an old community plugin. You should probably directly reach out to the Thingsboard developers. Note: Gatling Enterprise does have an official MQTT plugin, see https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/mqtt/.

Comment: Hi Stephane, Thank you for your answer. You are right, but as you said it is Enterprise, and I'm evaluating tools with near-zero budget, so I was in the search of workarounds. Also Thingsboard still advertises its performance achievements based on this plugin in their official documentation https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/performance-tools/#performance-tests-project, so I thought it would be still working. I don't know how to reach TB developers, but I'll try to find out how.